# nested loop in python is not looping more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm expecting an output of six line, 3 values for 'name' and ''timeZone_label' but when i run a nested for loop i think the loop is looping only once and it returns 3 line. my approach is to loop the list FILEDS and get one value at time and then use this value in the dictionary to loop and get the value of the key which are in the list.
thanks in advance

```
path=r'C:\Users\karthik\Desktop\udacity\t1.csv'
with open (path,'r') as p:
    reader=csv.DictReader(p)
    FIELDS = ["name", "timeZone_label"]
    for i in FIELDS:
        for row in reader:
            print (row[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DictReader` can only loop over the csv file once, returning a dict for each row in the file.

If you want to process your data by columns you need either to re-read the file multiple times with

```
FIELDS = ["name", "timeZone_label"]
for i in FIELDS:
    with open (path,'r') as p:
        reader=csv.DictReader(p)
        for row in reader:
            print (row[i])
```

or you will need to read all the rows in a list and loop multiple times over the list with something like

```
with open (path,'r') as p:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(p))
    FIELDS = ["name", "timeZone_label"]
    for i in FIELDS:
        for row in data:
            print (row[i])
```